# JavaScript "this" references the wrong object within an event handler

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm writing some MVC JavaScript code using Prototype. The problem is that when I reference `this` in the snippet below it does of course reference the Window object, whereas I need it to refer to my Controller instance so it can invoke my `updateValue` function, passing the HTML element ID.

I think I have to use [bind](http://prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) or [bindAsEventListener](http://prototypejs.org/api/function/bindAsEventListener) but I don't really understand how.

```
var Foo = {
  Controller: Class.create({
    observeEvents: function() {
      $$("#myform input").each(function(input) {
        input.observe("blur", this.updateValue(input.id); // <- wrong this!
      });
    },

    updateValue: function(elementID) {
      ...
    }
  })
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
    observeEvents: function() {
      var Controller = this;
      $$("#myform input").each(function(input) {
        input.observe("blur", Controller.updateValue.bind(Controller, input.id));
      });
     ...
```

If you don't ever want to learn how to use `bind` (and frankly I don't blame you) then you can forget about it and just use another teensy closure.

```
    observeEvents: function() {
      var Controller = this;
      $$("#myform input").each(function(input) {
        input.observe("blur", function(event) {
                                Controller.updateValue(input.id);
                              });
      });
     ...
```

Comment: bind is so useful everyone should know how to use it, if only to better understand the scope of their functions and how they relate.

Comment: IMHO - one cannot program JS without understanding bind.

Comment: I tried using `bind` as per your first example and it didn't work. The second example does work. Thank you.

Comment: The `bind` example doesn't works because inside the `each` callback, `this` refers to the Global object.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe jQuery has just spoiled me. I don't think I've ever actually used `bind`. Surprisingly often you can just write `$("#myform input").live("blur", updateValue)` and move on to the next problem.

Comment: Sigh, I just checked, and of course jQuery doesn't support `live("blur"...)`.

Comment: @John Topley: CMS was right. I edited the post to fix the bug.

Comment: @Jason, you are still using `this` inside the `each` loop, you need `Controller.updateValue.bind(Controller, input.id)`